# link query isnt working in realm

Tags: android, realm

i have following json structure

```
Appointment (Appointment name in model )
    |
    |___AppointmentList (appointmentLists name in model)
        |
        |__sync (sync name in model )
        |__subject
        |__time
```

now i am trying to fetch sync = 1 but its returning all the data whether sync has 1 or 0

```
 final Realm realm = getRealm();
        RealmResults<Appointment> appointment = 
            realm.where(Appointment.class).equalTo("appointmentLists.sync",NOT_SYNC).findAll();

realm.close();
```

it only works in following case

```
 RealmResults<AppointmentList> appointmentList = 
 realm.where(AppointmentList.class).equalTo("sync",RestApi.NOT_SYNC).findAll();


@JsonObject
public class Appointment extends RealmObject {

    @JsonField
    private String status;

    @JsonField
    private String errorMessage;

    @JsonField
    private String count;


    @PrimaryKey
    @JsonField
    private String userId;

    @JsonField
    private String organizationId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getOrganizationId() {
        return organizationId;
    }

    public void setOrganizationId(String organizationId) {
        this.organizationId = organizationId;
    }


    @JsonField(name ="appointments" , typeConverter = AppointmentListConverter.class)
    private RealmList<AppointmentList> appointmentLists;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is by design. You query from the perspective of the class you specified, in this case `Appointment`. We don't return "partial" classes which is what it sounds like you are looking for.

If you want a reference to your parent `Appointment` from the `AppointmentList` it should be part of the model definition for `AppointmentList`. Right now it is a reference you have to maintain manually, but we have an issue for automatically creating it. The concept is called backlinks: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607

If you want to use an existing converter process I would probably use `realm.copyFromRealm` and do a manual filter:

```
Realm realm = getRealm();
RealmResults<Appointment> results = realm.where(Appointment.class).equalTo("appointmentLists.sync",NOT_SYNC).findAll();

List<Appointment> copiedResults = realm.copyFromRealm(results);
for (Appointment a : copiedResults ) {
  Iterator<AppointmentList> it = a.getAppointmentLists().iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    AppointmentList item = it.next();
    if (item.getSync() == RestApi.NOT_SYNC) {
      it.remove();
    }  
  }
}

sendNotSyncedAppointments(copiedList);
```

Comment: whats the alternative as we have used realm in our project extensively. see my model in edits

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: i am fetching data those are not synced from realm db and convert it into json (using logansquare serializer ) and sending it to server

Comment: Then I am not sure I understand the problem. Your second query correctly finds all AppointmentList objects that are not synced? Those could easily be sent to the server?

Comment: well no as i need some of the fields exist in Appointment class too. like userId and organizationId

Comment: jsut like this `{"appointments":[{"activityid":"","alletec_customer":"e09f7c51-100d-e611-95ef-00155d644d28","location":"1212.22121","operationCode":"1","regardingobjectid":"f43a0a64-a32f-e511-afb0-005056a65203","scheduledend":"1462215840000","scheduledstart":"1462212240000","subject":"final meeting"}],"organizationId":"8bd4e01f-0ef7-e511-8f01-00155d644d28","userId":"e2f06d6d-bc65-e411-ba52-005056a65203"}`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Right now you will have to manually maintain that reference, but once #607 has been implemented it can be done automatically.

Comment: i dont know how to use it after `RealmResults<AppointmentList> appointmentList = realm.where(AppointmentList.class).equalTo("sync",RestApi.NOT_SYNC).findAll();`

Comment: There are many ways to go about this, but if you already have some sort of conversion process in place I would probably use `realm.copyFromRealm()` instead and do a manual filter before converting to JSON. I'll update my answer with an example